# Problems displaying a PHP array using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I'm having issues displaying contents from an array (which can be between 0 and 3 elements) in html by using jquery. All of this is within the same php file.

```
<?php
... other code
$watchlistArray = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $watchlistArray[] = $row;
}
?>
```

The array will contain between 0 and 3 elements. 
Example outputs obtained using

```
<?php echo json_encode($watchlistArray)?>
```

**2 results**

```
[{"prod_id":"41","prod_name":"An old desk","prod_highest_price":"69.30","prod_picture":"2.jpg","prod_end_date":"2018-04-05 20:40:00"},{"prod_id":"58","prod_name":"A brand new Iphone 8!","prod_highest_price":"795.00","prod_picture":"1.jpg","prod_end_date":"2018-09-24 20:40:00"}]
```

**3 results**

```
[{"prod_id":"42","prod_name":"A new sofa","prod_highest_price":"153.00","prod_picture":"3.jpg","prod_end_date":"2018-04-06 20:40:00"},{"prod_id":"41","prod_name":"An old desk","prod_highest_price":"69.30","prod_picture":"2.jpg","prod_end_date":"2018-04-05 20:40:00"},{"prod_id":"40","prod_name":"An old chair","prod_highest_price":null,"prod_picture":"2.jpg","prod_end_date":"2018-04-12 20:40:00"}]
```

Now for displaying this using jquery and html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            size = <?php echo sizeof($watchlistArray);?>;
            if (size === 0) {
                $('#watchlist0').html('No one has bidded on this item!');
            }

            if (size >= 1) {
                $('#watchlist0').html('                        <a href="../product/productPage.php?prod_ID=<?php echo $watchlistArray[0]["prod_id"]; ?>">\n' +
                    '                            <img src="../Browse/Images/<?php echo $watchlistArray[0]["prod_picture"] ?>"\n' +
                    '                                 class="img-rounded img-responsive">\n' +
                    '                        </a>\n' +
                    '                        <h4><?php echo $watchlistArray[0]["prod_name"] ?></h4>\n' +
                    '                        Current price: <strong><?php echo $watchlistArray[0]["prod_highest_price"] ?></strong>');
            }

            if (size >= 2) {
                $('#watchlist1').html('                        <a href="../product/productPage.php?prod_ID=<?php echo $watchlistArray[1]["prod_id"]; ?>">\n' +
                    '                            <img src="../Browse/Images/<?php echo $watchlistArray[1]["prod_picture"] ?>"\n' +
                    '                                 class="img-rounded img-responsive">\n' +
                    '                        </a>\n' +
                    '                        <h4><?php echo $watchlistArray[1]["prod_name"] ?></h4>\n' +
                    '                        Current price: <strong><?php echo $watchlistArray[1]["prod_highest_price"] ?></strong>');
            }

            if (size >= 3) {
                alert ("case 3")
                $('#watchlist2').html('                        <a href="../product/productPage.php?prod_ID=<?php echo $watchlistArray[2]["prod_id"]; ?>">\n' +
                    '                            <img src="../Browse/Images/<?php echo $watchlistArray[2]["prod_picture"] ?>"\n' +
                    '                                 class="img-rounded img-responsive">\n' +
                    '                        </a>\n' +
                    '                        <h4><?php echo $watchlistArray[2]["prod_name"] ?></h4>\n' +
                    '                        Current price: <strong><?php echo $watchlistArray[2]["prod_highest_price"] ?></strong>');
            }
        })
    </script>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4" align="center" id="watchlist0">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" align="center" id="watchlist1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" align="center" id="watchlist2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried this in several different ways (using a switch statement, loop, etc), but I always come across the same issue. The information only displays when there are 3 elements in the array. If i take out the code that runs when size >=3, then I get 2 images and other information displaying for when there are both 3 and 2 elements. This is really bizarre and I've been trying for hours - please help a struggling student.

**UPDATE**

Thank you everyone for the suggestions. As the output is static, I have implemented this in php using a switch statement with html echoes.

```
<?php
$arrSize = sizeof($watchlistArray);
switch ($arrSize) {
    case 0:
        echo "case 0 HTML";
        break;

    case 1:
        echo 'case 1 HTML';
        break;

    case 2:
        echo 'case 3 HTML';
        break;

    case 3:
        echo 'case 3 HTML';
}
?>
```

Probably not the most efficient way of doing this (as each echo refers to the same HTML elements) but it does work!

Comment: Why are you mixing php and javascript, the output seems to be static and depending on the value of the php variable, so there does not seem to be any need for javascript.

Comment: I'd recommend you view the source the browser receives being generated by the php. You could even update your question with it above.

Comment: @jeroen I did it this way and it worked well. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you solved the problem - as I just saw, I'll post my answer. Maybe it helps you further. I am not 100% sure what you were trying to achieve by those conditions, but I supposed that you want to display a *col-sm-4* div for each product found in the `$watchlistArray`.

Indeed, no js is needed, unless you're performing an ajax request to fetch the data from the db. Please note that in my code I changed the name of the variable `$watchlistArray` to `$products`, because I found it more suitable for me. In principle, the code reads all the products in the products list and displays them in *col-sm-4* cells. If the number of products in the products list exceeds the maximal number of products displayable in a row (*3* in your case), then a new row is created. You can run the code as it is.

A note: try to avoid using php constructs inside js codes. Php variable values can be passed as arguments to js functions instead, which can be called on event attributes (onclick, onload, etc) of html elements.

```
<?php
// This is just a hard-coded list. Build it as you wish (with db data for example).
$products = [
    [
        'prod_id' => '42',
        'prod_name' => 'A new sofa',
        'prod_highest_price' => '153.00',
        'prod_picture' => '3.jpg',
        'prod_end_date' => '2018-04-06 20:40:00'
    ],
    [
        'prod_id' => '41',
        'prod_name' => 'An old desk',
        'prod_highest_price' => '69.30',
        'prod_picture' => '2.jpg',
        'prod_end_date' => '2018-04-05 20:40:00'
    ],
    [
        'prod_id' => '40',
        'prod_name' => 'An old chair',
        'prod_highest_price' => null,
        'prod_picture' => '2.jpg',
        'prod_end_date' => '2018-04-12 20:40:00'
    ],
    [
        'prod_id' => '57',
        'prod_name' => 'An interesting book',
        'prod_highest_price' => '18.86',
        'prod_picture' => '2.jpg',
        'prod_end_date' => '2018-04-21 15:18:23'
    ],
    [
        'prod_id' => '58',
        'prod_name' => 'A big apple',
        'prod_highest_price' => '12.19',
        'prod_picture' => '2.jpg',
        'prod_end_date' => '2018-04-23 03:09:55'
    ],
];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo</title>

        <!-- CSS resources -->
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- JS resources -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            .row {
                padding-top: 20px;
                padding-bottom: 20px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
            }

            .product {
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <?php
            if (isset($products) && $products) {
                $numberOfProductsPerRow = 3; /* How many products should be allowed in a row? */
                $numberOfDisplayedProductsPerRow = 0; /* How many products are already displayed in a row? */

                foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
                    $productId = $product['prod_id'];
                    $productPicture = $product['prod_picture'];
                    $productName = $product['prod_name'];
                    $productHighestPrice = $product['prod_highest_price'];

                    if ($numberOfDisplayedProductsPerRow % $numberOfProductsPerRow === 0) {
                        ?>
                        <div class="row">
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 product" id="product<?php echo $key; ?>">
                            <a href="../product/productPage.php?prod_ID=<?php echo $productId; ?>">
                                <img src="../Browse/Images/<?php echo $productPicture; ?>" class="img-rounded img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $productName; ?>">
                            </a>

                            <h4>
                                <?php echo $productName; ?>
                            </h4>

                            <div>
                                Current price: <span class="highest-price"><?php echo $productHighestPrice; ?></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        $numberOfDisplayedProductsPerRow++;

                        if ($numberOfDisplayedProductsPerRow === $numberOfProductsPerRow) {
                            $numberOfDisplayedProductsPerRow = 0;
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
            } else {
                ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        No one has bidded on this item!
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I like this much more than the way I did it and I learnt a few new things too. Thanks!

Comment: @AakashBhalla You are welcome. I am glad that I could help you and, especially, that you could learn new things from my answer. Tip: you can apply a _modulo_ operation whenever it's about building rows/cells dynamically. I wish you best luck.

Answer (score 0):

your conditions are overlapping..

```
if(size>=2)
```

and

```
if(size>=3)
```

will both be called when there's 3 elements.. try to replace them with

```
if(size==2)
...........
if(size>=3)
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem since (size == 0) also doesn't work.
For example:
<?php echo json_encode($watchlistArray)?> returns []. size ==0 doesn't work.

Comment: your condition is checking for size if (size === 0) which checks if the value is 0 and if the size is an integer... try if (size == 0) or if size === "0"

Comment: as you should notice, even though the conditions overlap, the *result* would be correct because the indexes are hardcoded. notice how the code in the if (size >= 1) invokes the [1] key of the array?